# Compile Error: Argument Not Optional within Highlight Macro

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro in Excel to highlight a certain set of words in order to support keyword search analytics. I have this macro in `word-vba`. What do I need to change to translate to `excel-vba`. Currently, I keep getting an error that says

> Compile Error: Argument Not Optional

and the `.Find` text is highlighted, so that may be the main thing to fix.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to fix/translate this for excel?

```
Sub HighlightTargets()

    Dim range As range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim TargetList

    TargetList = Array("password", "login", "account")

    For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)
        Set range = ActiveDocument.range

        With range.Find
            .Text = TargetList
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False

            Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
                range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
            Loop
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Read how to use `Range.Find` expression [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

Comment: document.Range is a method, so it needs the open/close parens. So, ActiveDocument.Range()

Comment: `TargetList ` is an array and you are looping through its bound. While passing it to `Find` use `TargetList(i)`.

Comment: @RichHolton Good point but VBA pass that point by its default setting.

Comment: Thanks! @RichHolton. I still get the error message when I use `TargetList(i)` - would that be the only change?

Comment: Thanks! @Masoud. I still get the error message when I use `TargetList(i)` - would that be the only change?

Comment: Your code is for Word, not Excel.

Comment: As @Rory mentioned there are so many changes to make. `Range.Find` works differently in excel and I pointed you to the source where you can find out what expression you have and how you should write them (in parenthesis). Also, `dim range as range` is the worst idea try some different name rather the range itself. `Dim` your array as `Variant`. Your loop needs to be edited for cells within excel. While setting the range you need to refer to the `ActiveSheet` instead of the document which is for `word-vba`. List goes on and on.

Comment: Understood that there are a lot of problems, that has been made clear. I am trying to use a macro in Excel - apologies for wrong code...